Flux residue under BGA - How to remove?
Is there any way to properly remove Flux residue under a BGA package?
Isopropanol won't work here.

Depends on the type of flux used.

@evildemonic I used No-Clean flux BTFO-81-1H

There is a cleaning technology called "HFE co-solvent cleaning" which may be able to clean the situation you describe.
It uses HFE (hydrofluoroethers) in a vapour phase which then condenses on the cleaning target and rinses away the flux, assisted by ultrasound. This is not a complete description of the process. One substance used in such processes is called "Novec High Tech Fluid" from 3M. For example, a company called riebesam.de makes such cleaning machines, but there are certainly others.
There are at least 2 or 3 manufacturers of such machines.
In the past I have evaluated such a cleaning process on dense ultra low leakage SMD boards to remove flux residues under SMD passives. It turned out that this process was able to remove all flux residues - not only in the small cavities underneath SMD passives such as resistors and capacitors, but also in the 25µm grooves around SMD pads and solder stop masks with a width:depth ratio greater than 1. The cavity underneath the 0805 components was about 1mm long, 0.8mm wide and only ~15µm high - everything was completely clean afterwards, even when inspected with a microscope - the cleanest PCB I've ever seen.
No other cleaning process was able to remove any flux down to the microscopic level: all typical water+agent based processes failed and even C02 snow blasting failed to reach the tight cavities.
Flux-free soldering could not really compete either - and was far more complex to establish as a process.

Unless you are underfilling the BGA, there is no reason to remove a legitimate, high quality "no clean" (aka "leave-on") flux from underneath it. Their commonly used malic, succinic, etc., Weak Organic Acid (WOA) fluxes, are activated during soldering, and then encapsulated and sealed off within a durable matrix. If you try, and incompletely remove these residues, you open yourself up to future problems because the destruction of the encapsulating matrix leaves the remaining residues exposed to humidity, dendritic growth, etc. The alcohol you're flushing over those joints is also distributing that decomposed flux over nearby components and traces. The saponifiers that remove no-cleans are chemically complex, heated, applied with high pressure sprays or agitation followed by a thorough DI rinsing. On the manufacturing floor this is done by large in-line cleaners. Companies like Senju, Multicore and Kester all make excellent no-clean pastes and cored solders. Open up any modern-day electronic assembly and you'll find that it's soldered with leave-on (and probably lead free) paste & hand solders as companies long ago started ditching the costly and maintenance burdens of in-line cleaning. Under no circumstances use any solder that is classified as Organic Acid (OA) - "water soluble." They contain very aggressive fluxes which MUST BE COMPLETELY REMOVED and will quickly ruin a board if this isn't done 110%. My company had an iron-clad policy that forbid any "spot cleaning" of OA flux assemblies. They all had to go back through the cleaner.
